# Is static function hot-swappable in java eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hotswap

I know you can modify a method in Eclipse and hot swap it.  That was implemented using dynamically load class?  So what about static methond of a class, if I modify it in run time, can you swap it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should try it and see for yourself.  :-)  But in my experience, yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not sure about static class variable at the moment.